# System shortcut depending on the language

Tags: qt, system, shortcut

I have a QT application with a large text, and I would like to show a 'Search' box when user clicks the system shortcut for this functionality. But this shortcuts depends on the current system language. I mean for example, in Windows + English, Search = "CRTL + F", but in Windows + Spanish, Search = "CRTL + B".

How can I manage this issue and detect the good shorcut depending on the language? I would like to open my 'Search' box when the user presses CRTL+F (if system is in English), or when user presses CTRL+B (if system is in Spanish)

Thanks in advance,
Diego

Answer (score 2):

```
QShortcut* shortcut = new QShortcut(this);
shortcut->setContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);

QLocale::Language lang = QLocale::system().language();

switch (lang)
{
case QLocale::English:
        shortcut->setKey(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_F));
    break;

case QLocale::Spain:
        shortcut->setKey(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_B));
    break;

default:
        // or simply assign platform's standard key binding
        shortcut->setKey(QKeySequence::Find);
break;
}

connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, this, &MyClass::my_slot);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to say (sorry!) that my application has QML, I don't use  QWidgets for GUI. I have tried:

    Shortcut {
        sequence: StandardKey.Find
        context: Qt.ApplicationShortcut
        onActivated: console.log("find...")
    }

But 'activated' is only called with CTRL+F (not depending on the language)